# Rails object saves, but doesn't persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application for studying flashcards. It worked fine for months, then recently I made some slight changes while creating an API for a mobile app to work on top of it, and now the object no longer persists in the database (for reasons that should have nothing to do with the API).

The controller code is as follows:

```
flashcard.process_card_study(params['ease'].to_i)
debugger
flashcard.save!
```

`process_card_study` is a model method that changes the attributes according to the user's response. That still works fine - when I check the object with the debugger, the attributes have been changed appropriately. Then I run the next line of code to save it, and everything seems to work:

`(0.8ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "flashcards" SET "repetition_streak" = $1, "next_study_date" = $2, "times_studied" = $3, "last_recall_quality" = $4, "last_study_date" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "flashcards"."id" = $7  [["repetition_streak", 0], ["next_study_date", "2018-01-26 00:00:00"], ["times_studied", 1], ["last_recall_quality", 4], ["last_study_date", "2018-01-26 00:00:00"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-26 18:48:42.307211"], ["id", 200]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT`

I then check if the object still has the correct attributes (in the debugger still), and it does. however, when I come out of the debugger, the object is back to its original state!!

The only callbacks I have on the object is an after_initialize, which sets all the values back to the initial state. This seems like it could be a culprit, although if the callback was run, the values would be reset in the debugger too, which they aren't. What's more, I was under the impression that a save call would not run an after_initialize callback.

Any help or pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated.
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html say:

> Blockquote
>   after_find and after_initialize callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with after_initialize being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.

It means that every time you find this object after debugger, the callback sets everything back.

```
f = FlashCard.new  # the after_initialize is called
f.save             # after initialize is not called
f = FlashCard.last # or find or whatever the after_initialize is called again and resets everything
```

So you can make a workaround with your after_initialize to work only with not persisted records like this:

```
after_initialize :do_something, if: :new_record?
def do_something
  # do something
end
```